# BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable Python in Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I am constantly getting the following error when running Python script via socket on Cygwin:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:/view/cmtest_ccProxy/bce/cmTools/lib/CC.py", line 321, in standAlone
    results = Process.execute (cmd = cmd, opts = opts)
  File "M:/view/cmtest_ccProxy/bce/cmTools/lib/Process.py", line 327, in execute
    timeout = timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 535, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1382, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The setup is:
Server side:
Cygwin + inetd + python built for cygwin
Client side:
telnet server

The python script runs command with large output.

```
import subprocess, os, tempfile, re
def execute (cmd = None,
         opts = None,
         log = None,
         verify = False,
         cmdlog = False,
         audit = False,
         logappend = False,
         ignorestatus = False,
         umask = None,
         host = None,
         interrupt = None,
         timeout = None,
         forceaudit = False):
global __signal
global __signalList
returnData = {"status": 0, "rawstatus": 0, "interrupt": 0,
              "stdout": None, "stderr": None}
os.environ["ENV"] = ""

stdOutHandle, stdOut = tempfile.mkstemp (text = True)
stdErrHandle, stdErr = tempfile.mkstemp (text = True)

if re.match ("\s", cmd): cmd = "'" + cmd + "'"
cmd = [cmd]
opts = opts.split()
cmd.extend (opts)

if not verify:
    if umask: originalUmask = os.umask (umask)

    if interrupt:
        for idex, item in enumerate (__signalList):
            if item: signal.signal (idex, interrupt)
    __signal = 0

    returnData["rawstatus"] = subprocess.call (cmd, stdout = stdOutHandle,
                                               stderr = stdErrHandle,
                                               timeout = timeout)
    returns = returnData["rawstatus"]
```

Any lights would be appreciated!

Br,

Comment: did you find any solution?